# Android 3.0 emulator launching issue

Tags: android, halting-problem

I am trying to test a simple status bar notification program on Android 3.0 emulator.
When I try to run my application from eclipse, sometimes either I see a message that `apk can't be installed` when I check the DDMS log, I see java `outOfMemory` error. Though my application is fairly simple just one java file.

Sometimes when I launches my emulator it shut down my windows completely. I tested this on `Windows XP` and `Ubuntu` as well. In `Ubuntu` too when emulator was about to launch completely and showing home page my OS crashes.

Any other version of Android works well on my PC like `2.2`, `2.3`. I see this issue only with `3.0` (honecomb) version. Any resolution to this?

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Well when making an AVD from the AVD Manager , assign it maybe 200 -500 mb and this issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the resource usage while running 3.0 is much more than 2.3 and below. The error you are getting refers to the emulator/eclipse needing more memory not your application. How much memory and CPU do you have?

Comment: i have 2 Gb RAM. probably my problem got resolved. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: i am again facing the same problem. My PC shut down ehen the emulator starts from eclipse. I have 2 GB of ram in my laptop. I also fixed the RAM size for 3.0 emulator to 500. but again it behaves abnoramally. it this something known with 3.0 version?